# How to handle character sets properly in conjunction with a database, text areas etc etc

Tags: php, mysql, html

For once and for all I want to have clear how to handle ü etc in my application. 
I understand using UTF-8 is the best way to store/represent these strange characters.

So I declare in my HTML a meta-charset:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Storing the content in my database, it also needs the right set so I set the collation to `utf8_general_ci`

[image: unicode]

In my understanding there isn't an other place where I can define the character set. But what is the problem?

If I go into phpMyAdmin and add jülich in the content field, and I subtract the content from the database through a mysql query and PHP. The ü gets displayed properly. 
But if I view it in a Textarea it displays a black diamond shaped figure with a white ? in it.

If I put in the text in a textarea in my application and submit it, it displays correct in the text area. But on the website it displays Ã¼

These are the charset settings in the startup screen of phpMyAdmin:
[image: phpMyadmin]

As an answer on questions off Daan:

character%:

[image: phpMyadmin]

```
character_set_client = utf8
character_set_connection = utf8
character_set_database = utf8
character_set_filesystem = binary
character_set_results = utf8
character_set_server = latin1
character_set_system = utf8
character_sets_dir = /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

collation%

[image: phpMyadmin]

```
collation_connection = utf8_general_ci
collation_database = utf8_general_ci
collation_server = latin1_swedish_ci
```

How can I resolve this?

**Things I've done so far:**

added: `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

added: `$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");`

added: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

added: `$this->db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, 
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));`

**Solution**

All the above is working like a charm. But if you use a function to replace certain special routines and return the replaced string through `utf8_decode()` it obviously doesn't display the ü ;(

Comment: Could you show us the output for `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character'` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%'`queries from both phpMyAdmin and your own PHP code?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%'`, of course

Comment: @Daan I've added the results to my original question. It appears that the `collation_connection` is different. Should I change that? How can I do that?

Comment: All of this looks fine...is there anywhere we can see this live?

Comment: It's part of a big web app which is 'private'. Sent an mail to me: richard@sturb.nl

Comment: Can you put together a small example that illustrates only this problem and host it somewhere? Also, does unicodelookup.com help you at all when you copy in this character as it is represented in the HTML source?

Comment: I found the problem! A substitution function returned an str which it ran trough `utf8_decode()` .... grrrrrrrrr

Answer (score 1):

You should really read the [MySQL specific PDO documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) as it clearly states that the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND constant can only be used in the driver_options array when constructing a new database handle.

So instead of using setAttribute you should specify the MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND when you create the PDO handle, like this :

```
$this->db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, 
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Comment: Adding it to the creation of the object didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's probably a browser side thing.  A couple more things to check into:

1. What is your web server sending for the `Content-Type` header?  does it use `charset=utf-8`?
2. Do you have a different character set specified in the `DOCTYPE` of your HTML page?

Comment: The server sends this: `Content-Type:text/html`
This is the doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @stUrb - one other thing I can think of would be to check the client character set for your MySQL connection from PHP.  You can test that by calling `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` after establishing your database connection.

Comment: I'm using PDO, so adding tho `$this->db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");' doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure phpMyAdmin *itself* is properly configured to use UTF8.  It sounds like it is not.